# Keras fit_generator throwing ValueError

Tags: generator, keras

So I'm trying to create a generator to iterate through a data set for use in training with Keras's fit_generator. Here's the definition of the generator, the model, and the call to fit_generator:

```
import numpy as np
from queue import Queue, deque
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

num_features = 40
len_data = 100
data = np.random.rand(len_data, num_features)

def train_generator(train_idxs):
    while True:
        i = train_idxs.get(block=False)
        training_example = data[i,:]
        training_example.shape = (1, len(training_example))

        yield (training_example, training_example)


layer0_size = num_features
layer1_size = layer0_size / 2
layer2_size = layer1_size / 2

layers = []
layers.append(
    Dense(input_dim=layer0_size, output_dim=layer1_size, activation='relu'))
layers.append(
    Dense(input_dim=layer1_size, output_dim=layer2_size, activation='relu'))
layers.append(
    Dense(input_dim=layer2_size, output_dim=layer1_size, activation='relu'))
layers.append(
    Dense(input_dim=layer1_size, output_dim=layer0_size, activation='sigmoid'))

model = Sequential()
for layer in layers:
    model.add(layer)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

train_idxs = Queue()
train_idxs.queue = deque(range(len_data))
train_gen = train_generator(train_idxs)
max_q_size = 2
model.fit_generator(train_gen, samples_per_epoch=len(data), max_q_size=max_q_size, nb_epoch=1)
```

Keras will then successfully train 98/100 training examples and throw this error

```
 98/100 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6930Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 429, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(self._generator)
  File "scrap.py", line 12, in train_generator
    i = train_idxs.get(block=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/queue.py", line 161, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap.py", line 43, in <module>
    model.fit_generator(train_gen, samples_per_epoch=len(data), max_q_size=max_q_size, nb_epoch=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 935, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1528, in fit_generator
    str(generator_output))
ValueError: output of generator should be a tuple (x, y, sample_weight) or (x, y). Found: None
```

It seems like what's happening is that it popped of all of the training_idxs and it's still trying to get more until Keras exhaust the training examples in its internal queue. Is there a way to get it to stop trying to get more training examples from the generator?

Comment: Why do you use this generator in a such cumbersome way? Is there are reason behind a usage like this? Basically - it's impossible to stop generator from taking next examples and putting it to the queue. But maybe there is a different way to solve your scenario.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I'm not sure which part you believe is cumbersome. This is a simplified example of my actual use case. In reality data isn't a numpy array. It is an object that makes a connection to a file from which data is pulled out as needed. I use the queue so that I can spread the data collection across several worker threads. I don't think it's true that you can't stop fit_generator from getting new examples. It's supposed to stop after its retrieved num_samples_per_epoch. Would you write this code any differently?

Comment: If you read `fit_generator` documentation it's mentioned there that generator should yield data indefinitely.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I see! Thank you.

Comment: I can recommend using https://keras.io/utils/#sequence Sequence class - it allows you to create a generator "class" that doesn't have to yield things indefinitely